# I have a consistent error with my source

Tags: java, jframe, syntax-error

I am new to java and I have an error that will not leave no matter what and I cannot understand what is happening

the code starts with this class

```
 public class Window extends JFrame{    
    JFrame mediaform = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        public static void load(){                  
            public mediaform(){         
                 (bunch of code for the program)                                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the error occurs with the "`public mediaform(){`" and if I fix that "`public static void load(){`"

Comment: There's a method within a method within a third method. You can't nest methods. Also, there's no return type for `mediaform()`, and it's not a constructor.

Comment: Close one brace before opening the next one...

Comment: but the "public mediaform(){" must be under the load method so I am really confused

Comment: Try concept of `inner class`.

Comment: what would that look like

Comment: @HaydenSim you cannot define a method inside another method. You want to solve this problem or you wanna know why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

please read tutorial with java core..
can't be a nested function..
your class may be should like this...

```
 public class MediaForm extends JFrame{
    public MediaForm(){
    }
    public static void load(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
           (bunch of code for the program)
    }
}
```

Comment: it starts with 

public class Window extends JFrame{

public static void load(){

JFrame window = new JFrame();

public window(){

(code)

}
}
}


sorry about the name changes but the "public window(){" has to be under the load method

Comment: it's **public Window()** not public window()

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring methods inside your main method, they should be on the same level

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
JFrame mediaform = new JFrame();
public static void main(String[] args){...}

public static void load(){...}

public static void mediaform(){...} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare method in another method. It is not allowed. Please make  the method declare seperated.

Regarding method  **mediaform() {**, you need to set is as void type as well.

Below is an example after modfication:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

JFrame mediaform = new JFrame();

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public static void load() {

}

public void mediaform() {

    {
        // (bunch of code for the program)

    }
}

}
```

Comment: this was helpful but is there a way I can load the "public void mediaform" in the load method as this isn't the main class

Comment: Since the load method is **static void**, you can declare mediaform as **static void** as well. And you can call mediaform() method in load method using the following way.  public static void load() {
  mediaform();
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void load(){                  
    public mediaform(){         
        (bunch of code for the program)                                 
    }
}
```

1. You cannot write a method into another method.
2. `public... mediaform()` You didn't write any return type or you don't want to return anything, maybe you should write `void`:

   ```
   public static  void mediaform()
   ```

   or

   ```
   public  [return type] mediaform()
   ```
3. About `static`. You can call the method in another class if you declare the method `static`. if you want call the method in another class, maybe you can write `ClassName.MethodName` (this method is which you declare `static`). If you don't write `static`, you still call the method in another class, maybe you can write

   ```
   ClassName a = new ClassName;
   a.MethodName();
   ```

   on the premise that the method is declared `public`. If not, you can't call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define method inside another. And if `mediaform()` is a method then there should be a return type to method. After reading your post I assume that mediaform() is not a constructor so here is my answer.

```
class Window extends JFrame {
    JFrame mediaform = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //call load() method
    }

    public static void load() {
        //Your code
        //call mediaform() method
    }

    public void mediaform() {
       //(bunch of code for the program)
    }
}
```